# Shellcode: perform 2 execve() calls

Tags: c, assembly, buffer-overflow, shellcode, execve

I am trying to write shellcode in assembly. I need to perform a `/usr/bin/killall` command AND a `/usr/bin/wget` command. I have both commands running perfectly in shellcode with the `execve()` syscall. But now I want to combine these 2, but this is not possible because the program exits when the first `execve()` call is executed. (from the man pages of `execve()` : `execve()` does not return on success).

How can I perform 2 `execve()` calls? Or is there another way to call both `/usr/bin/killall` and `/usr/bin/wget` from the same shell code?

Greets and thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is it you want to "write shell code in assembly"? Usually you'd write in C and have it compiled. Running two commands in succession is what the shell is designed for and doing it in assembly will provide little gain...

Comment: use fork, then if, and two execves.

Answer (score 5):

When you use the exec-family of functions, the program you call it with is substituted into the current process. So when the first execve-call is made, your entire process image disappears, and thus second call is never made. To get around this you must fork another process before calling execve.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not possible to execute two `execve()` one after the other. Simply because, by definition, the `execve()` call will override the memory of the original process with the new one and you will never be able to switch back to the original process again.

The second option that you propose (merging `/usr/bin/killall` and `/usr/bin/wget` into the shellcode) is perfectly possible if the `killall` command is not killing the process executing the shellcode itself. If it is the case, I really need more information about why is this behavior is needed because it seems a bit absurd to me (but I certainly miss the context in which you are running your shellcode).